# Is it possible to animate the Grid.Column?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, attached-properties

Сan I animate `Grid.Column` property? I need to move `<Border>` in columns.

```
<Storyboard>
       <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Grid.Column" To="4" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>  
</Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `Grid.Column` is an attached property, you must add parentheses to the property path.

See [PropertyPath for Animation Targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/propertypath-xaml-syntax#propertypath-for-animation-targets).

```
<Int32Animation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)" To="4" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
```